# Is there an function to check if someone reacted on a message? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Anyone knows if there is an function to check if someone reacted on a message like the `once ready` event for Discord.JS?

```js
client.once('ready', function() {
    console.log('Bot succesfully loaded!')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd), **but it only emits for cached messages**.

Do not use once for this event. Use on, as otherwise only the first reaction will be emitted and then none after that.

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (messageReaction, user) {
    console.log(user.id + ' reacted with ' + messageReaction.emoji);
})
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'cached messages'?

Comment: The ID is returning 'null' for some reason, so no way checking if its an e.g poop emoji is it?

Comment: Only Custom Emojis have id's, poop emoji has `.name`.

Comment: Cached Messages are the ones sent, after your Bot fired the ready event and the ones manually fetched, with e.g. `channel.messages.fetch('id');`

Comment: Tried to log .name and still returned null.. Any ideas why?

Comment: Oh.. I did messageReaction.name xD. Now it works Thnx :)